# Compile all .c files in directory - and Subfolders - using GCC compiler in MSYS2

Tags: gcc, compilation, msys, msys2

is there a way to compile all `.c`files in the current directory - including all `.c` files in all subfolders.

Trying out the Wildcard like `gcc -c *.c` searches only in the current directory...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I think the MSYS environment should have the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command. That could be used.

Comment: `find $WORKSPACE -name "*.c" -exec gcc -c "{}" \;`
works very well for me, thanks!
My only further problem is, that when using this code snippet in Jenkins no error will be returned if one file isn't compilable...

Comment: Perhaps you should be researching the topic of *makefiles*? You can still find source files using similar techniques (even though I rather recommend you explicitly list the files you need, think of the case if you have an experimental source file that you don't want to build with), but error when building one source file will lead to the whole `make` process being aborted.

Comment: Works wonderful with a makefile, thank you very much!!